# Can I change the keyboard orientation?

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, orientation

For example I turn off autorotation with this code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return NO;
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return 0;
}
```

And my buttons, labels, textFields and other object can rotate according to the current orientation of the device. But keyboard doesn't want to rotate=/
How i can rotate keyboard or i can't. Who knows? 
Please help)
http://www.pictureshack.ru/images/8145_Snimok_ekrana_05_11_2013_18_55_00_s_Simulyatora_iOS.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Decision proved to be a simple.
In my method where i checked device orientation, i add this code and it's working.

```
    if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait){
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
    }
    else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown animated:NO];  
    }
    else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];
    }
    else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight){
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
}
```

Hope this helps to someone!)

Answer (score 1):

**Keyboard orientation is same as Status Bar orientation.**

in image, all your button and text orientation not in orientation of Status Bar.

**try following code**

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Oh not so helpful code, but… BUT! You give me a hint to solve the problem!