# Change only Keyboard orientation

Tags: iphone, keyboard, orientation

I need to change the keyboard orientation to landscape on a portrait mode screen.

This means that the screen would stay portrait while the keyboard turns to landscape mode.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: See these two links . This may help you.

  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15443637/2869784
  
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/19826115/2869784